# Add attribute to i18n strings in React Native

Tags: react-native, internationalization

I've already known how to generate i18n string through [react-native-i18n](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n). For example,

```js
// en.js  source
{
  "hello": "Hello, {{name}}."
}

// use
I18n.t("hello", { name: "John" })
```

and it shows `Hello, John.`.

I've also known how to generate attributed string:

```
<Text>
  This is a <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>bold<Text> word.
<Text>
```

and it shows `This is a`**`bold`**`word`.

The problem is, how can I add attributes to a i18n template string? Any library for this?

```
// en.js  source
{
  "hello": "Hello, <b>{{guest}}</b>. I'm {{host}}."
}

// use
I18n.t("hello", { guest: "John", host: "Sam" })
```

- Expected: `Hello,`**`John`**`. I'm Sam.`
- What I got: `Hello, <b>John</b>. I'm Sam.`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```js
const splitTitle = (title, style) => {
    const [left, center, right] = title.split(/<b>|<\/b>/)

    return (
        <Text style={style}>
            {left}
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'font-name', fontWeight: 'font-weight' }}>{center}</Text>
            {right}
        </Text>
    )
}
```

And call it

```js
splitTitle(i18n.t("key"), style)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-i18next it supports react content inside its translation component:

```react
<Trans i18nKey="userMessagesUnread" count={count}>
    Hello <strong title={t('nameTitle')}>{{name}}</strong>, you have {{count}} unread message. <Link to="/msgs">Go to messages</Link>.
</Trans>
```

In the dictionary,

```json
"userMessagesUnread": "Hello <1>{{name}}</1>, you have {{count}} unread message. <5>Go to message</5>.",
"userMessagesUnread_plural": "Hello <1>{{name}}</1>, you have {{count}} unread messages.  <5>Go to messages</5>.",
```

Learn more https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#using-with-react-components

Comment: Am I missing something here? Doesn't this solution make it so that you have hard coded English translations in your component?

Comment: Such a confused component

Comment: The question is for React Native

Comment: This doesn't work in react native.